# C , binary representation of unsigned int arg

Tags: c

How to use atoi to make pairCounts to produce this line?

`# ./paircounts 17
0`

`# ./paircounts 255
7`

`# ./paircounts 10 20
too many arguments!`

```
int pairCounts(unsigned int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char testStr[] = "# pairs in base 2 of %u = %d, should be %d\n";
    printf (testStr, 0, pairCount (0), 0);
    printf (testStr, 11, pairCount (11), 1);
    printf (testStr, 2863377066u, pairCount (2863377066u), 2);
    printf (testStr, 268435456, pairCount (268435456), 0);
    printf (testStr, 4294705151u, pairCount (4294705151u), 29);
    return 0;
}

int pairCounts(unsigned int n) {
}
```

Comment: The usual question: What have you tried?

Comment: I would also add, visit [THIS](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) site

Comment: userz2038240, please stop vandalizing your question. Normally, if you'd want to delete one of your questions, you could use the delete link just underneath it. You won't be able to do that if folks have posted answers, though. If you'd like to get rid of the content you've posted, consider using the `flag` link above to ask for help from a moderator.

Comment: perhaps you should just stop vandalizing this site?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use `atoi` for anything at all?  If you want to parse a string as an integer value, you ought to use `strol`.  And `atoi` is not even remotely suitable for producing output.  To generate the line:

```
# ./paircounts 17 0
```

you would use `puts` (or `fputs`, or `printf`, or `fprintf`, or possibly `fwrite`, or maybe `write`, ...) instead of `atoi`.  For example:  `puts( "# ./paircounts 17 0" )`.  Similarly for the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) page. I know its cplusplus.com but it is still valid for the c version of atoi. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but i have two ideas:

1. You are trying to check that the right number of arguments have come in. In this case you don't need atoi, you just need to check argc for the correct amount:

   ```
   if (argc != 3) throw some error;
   ```

   Remember that argc includes the program name so it will always be one more then  the actual input arguments.
2. You want to use atoi to do something else, in which case read the atoi guide because it is very simple to use.

If you want more clarification you will need to improve your question. Good luck.